# Read nested json in grunt

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs

I have the following objects in some dedicated json file:

```
{
  "obj1": {
    "firstField": "a",
    "secondField": "b"
  }
},
{
  "obj2": {
    "firstField": "c",
    "secondField": "d"
  }
}
```

I would like to read this json from my grunt file, inside initConfig.
I use:

```
    grunt.initConfig({
        configuration: grunt.file.readJSON('configuration.json')
      )
    }
```

Now I want to get Obj1 or Obj2 - and give them a name, so I could extract firstField generically.
Something like:

```
obj: '<%= configuration.obj1 %>
```

and then use:

```
 '<%= obj.firstField %>
```

But this one is not working. How can I do it?

Comment: I think you have answered the question yourself :) Just enclose it in Grunt template tags: `<%= configuration.obj.firstField %>`.

Comment: You are right... I'll edit my question because this is not my problem. Thanks